# UIRefreshControl can’t be disabled

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol, uicontrol

I have a UITableViewController inside a storyboard. I’ve enabled the pull to refresh property using interface builder.
I would like to disable and re enable the pull to refresh functionality programmatically upon request.

UIRefreshControl inherits from UIControl which have the isEnabled property.

Setting this property to false NEVER disables it, nor setting isUserInteractionEnabled to false.

The only way I can achieve what I want is by setting the refresh control to nil and then re create it again, but I still don’t understand why can’t I just set it’s isEnabled value to false?

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that UIRefreshControl inherits from UIControl, but [isEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618217-isenabled) = false, disables touch events. So the only way to "disable" UIRefreshControl is to set it to `nil`

Comment: But why simply disabling the touch event doesn’t enough to “turn it off”? This is exactly what I’m asking about...

Comment: Because this is not touch event, this is "pull to refresh" and the selector that responds to pull to refresh is .valueChanged not touchUpInside for example.

Comment: Interesting. I suggest you add this fact to the answer itself so it will be more clear for future viewers.